# Does d3.json() and JSON.parse() produce the same results?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am having an issue moving from loading an external JSON file to using a local json string. At first, it seemed like d3.json() returned the same JSON array that I got using JSON.parse() inside of a $.getJSON(), although, while they seem similar, it looks like d3.json added an "ID" variable to my JSON data. Which seems pretty important when constructing a [Sankey Graph in D3](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/c2637e28b79fb3bfea13). Also, using the exact same data, with $.getJSON() and JSON.parse(), this ID element is not present in the exact same output calls. Does D3 purposely add an "ID" element to its data? How do I achieve the same result with JSON.parse()?

So visually, the output of a console.log(mygraph) call appears like:

```
    Object {source: Object, target: Object, value: "0", path: "path#0", dy: 0}
    dy:0
    id:0
    path:"path#3"
    source:Object
    sy:0
    target:Object
    ty:0
    value:"0"
    __proto__:Object
```

But, the latter method with a console.log(mygraph) call appears like:

```
    Object {source: Object, target: Object, value: "0", path: "path#0", dy: 0}
    dy:0
    path:"path#3"
    source:Object
    sy:0
    target:Object
    ty:0
    value:"0"
    __proto__:Object
```

What exactly is this "ID" and how do I get it using the latter method? Actually, how do I load a local JSON variable into D3?

Comment: `d3.json` does not add any `id` attribute to the response, in fact the code is basically just `return JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);`

Comment: @RuuRuu, it's possible that you're not aware of this yet but, on StackOverflow, when people take the time to answer your questions — and if the answer is satisfactory — you should accept it (by clicking the check mark next to the answer) and/or upvote it. It looks like you've never done that.

Comment: Nope. Had no idea. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d3.json()` is like `$.getJSON()`, in that it takes a url string as the 1st param, and a function called when the data is loaded as 2nd param.

`JSON.parse()` does something else. It takes a string that looks like JSON and parses it into javascript objects like json.

Neither one will add anything such as an `id` param to the data it produces. `id` would have to be in the data you're loading/parsing.

One thing that might have happened to produce `id` is that you successfully loaded/parsed your data, then passed the it to another function that added the `id` prop. In that case, it's even possible that some of your confusion occurred from the way Chrome's `console.log` lets you expand whatever object you logged. The thing is that even if you `console.log`'ed your object BEFORE some other function added the `id` prop to it, BY THE TIME you clicked to expand it, it was already there and showed up.